# detect Richtextbox newline Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox, newline

i'm creating a `RichTextBox` with Syntax-Highlighting, my actual code can check for words that are separated from other words with space or with nothing with that statement:

```
        If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = " " Or RichTextBox1.SelectedText = Nothing Then
```

So when i type "test" (my highlighted word) on the `RichTextBox` it gets blue, it works on all cases, exept when i type "test", it gets blue, then i press enter, it gets black again, like if there is a character after the word.
I guess that the newline is represented by a character on the `RichTextBox` and thats why its not getting reconized only as "test", so whats the character i had to put on the if so it can check?

i tried this way:

```
If  RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "\n" Then
```

and:

```
If RichTextBox1.SelectedText = VbNewLine Then
```

but both didnt work, Anyone knows the character that means 'its a new line here'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a chr(10), a linefeed character. You can also use RichTextBox1.Lines if you want to handle each line separately.

Here's one way to look at single-byte characters in a RichTextBox:

```
For i = 1 To Len(rtext1.text)
  s = s & Asc(Mid(rtext1.text, i, 1)) & "  "
  Next i
MsgBox(s)
```